# Showing that a vector field $\vec{G} = (F_2(y, x), F_1 (y, x)$ is conservative given that $\vec{F} = (F_1 (x, y), F_2 (x, y))$ is conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The question is in the title. I have tried  a huge amount of counter-examples and have come to the conclusion that the vector field is conservative.

It can be shown by counter-example that the vector fields $\vec{G} = (F_1 (y,x), F_2 (y, x)$, and $(F_2 (x,y), F_1 (x, y)$ are not conservative. In essence the vector field in the question is a combination of these.

I have tried to directly compute the derivatives of the components of G but I always end up writing tautologies which do not prove anything.

I have also tried to generate some matrices which I could multiply G by to transform it, but I doubt there is a matrix that exists which would flip the internal components of the F components.

Any hints or suggestions as to how to continue?

Comment: Are you supposed to be showing this for $G = (F_2(y,x),F_1(y,x))$ maybe?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I have edited the title.

Comment: Of course this can be proven in a formal way. But it is intuitively obvious: When you draw ${\bf F}$ in the $(x,y)$-plane using small arrows you obtain ${\bf G}$ by reflecting "everything" with respect to the line $x=y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $F$ is conservative, then there is a $\phi$ so that

$$
F_1(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi(x,y)\\
F_2(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \phi(x,y)\\
$$

Let $\psi(x,y) = \phi(y,x)$. What are $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x,y)$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\psi(x,y)$?

Comment: This is actually precisely where I got stuck, am I allowed to assume the following properties? $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x,y) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi (y,x) = F_{1}(y, x)$?

Comment: Not quite; $\partial_x\phi(y,x) = F_2(y,x)$. If you forget about the original names of the variables, then it's immediate. It's maybe more obvious if you write $\partial_u \phi(v,u) = F_2(v,u)$, that's the *exact same statement* as $\partial_y \phi(x,y) = F_2(x,y)$.

Comment: Yes, that notation change helped a lot, now I can see more clearly where the relations came from. Is the proof then finished by concluding that $\partial_x\phi(y,x) = F_2(y,x)$ and $\partial_y\phi(y,x) = F_1(y, x)$, then it follows that $\vec{G} = (\partial_x\phi(y,x), \partial_y\phi(y,x)) = \nabla \phi(y,x) = \nabla \psi(x,y)$, and because $\psi(x,y) = \phi(y,x)$, we know that $\psi(x, y) \in C^{1} (R^2)$ because $\phi$ is the potential of F, and thus we now have a function $\psi$ that is differentiable, and further more its gradient gives G.

Comment: Yep, looks good.